# Tagging doesn't work in select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

ok, I have this simple select2 which needs tagging support.
My code :-

```
<select name="x1" id="x1" style="width: 20%">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

JS :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#x1").select2({
        tags: true
    });
});
```

My select2 should have tagging support, but it doesn't happen with my code. What wrong am I doing?
Jsfiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/u4euvsw0/

Answer (score 6):

You have to add "multiple" attribute to make it works

```
<select name="x1" id="x1" style="width: 20%" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use data-select2-tags="true" in your select like this:

```
<select name="x1" id="x1" style="width: 20%" data-select2-tags="true">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `multiple` and `tags` in the initialization.

```
<select name="x1" id="x1" style="width: 20%" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `multiple="multiple"` is the correct way to set the `multiple` attribute, not `multiple="true"`. Even better, just say `multiple` without setting another value and it will default to `multiple="multiple"`.

Comment: @KevinBrown Sorry... :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single tag system, you have to put the `minimumResultsForSearch` in the config on -1. This made it work for me.